# Blackberry. Showing hindi text?

Tags: blackberry

Does Blackberry able to show Hindi text in components.

Can I retrieve Hindi content from sql lite database and show in Blackberry Screen?

Without installing Desktop software can't w show Hindi text in Blackberry.

Comment: if your hand set support hindi font then it open with out any problem otherwise it wont open

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work always but Yes you can.This is what i did, first of all you will have to have the font file in the project folder  and then in your code apply font to the field that displays the text as follows

```
FontManager.getInstance().load("hindifont.TTF", "MyFont", FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) ;
    {
      try 
      {
        FontFamily typeface = FontFamily.forName("MyFont");
        Font myFont = typeface.getFont(Font.PLAIN, 19);
        yourfield.setFont(myFont);
        add(yourfield);
      } 
      catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) 
      {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }   
    }
```

you can also retrieve from sqlite db if it has a supporting text.